# Can I search two tables for a Username?

Tags: php, sql

I'm using the following query to find users in the 'Employer' table:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT password, salt
        FROM Employer
        WHERE Employer_Name = '$username';";
```

I have a second table called `Clients` (with the password & salt fields as well as a `username` field) , is it possible to search both tables for a single username?

(If any more information is required then let me know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need here is a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT password, salt, 'employer' as user_type
FROM Employer
WHERE Employer_Name = '$username'
UNION
SELECT password, salt, 'client' as user_type
FROM Clients
WHERE Clients_Name = '$username'
```

Comment: lol beat me to it Ben! +1 for thinking a head to differentiate between the entity being a client or employer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a UNION here.

```
SELECT password, salt FROM Employer WHERE Employer_Name = '$username';
UNION
SELECT password, salt FROM Clients WHERE Client_Name = '$username';"
```

This will return you one record set of all the values from both tables that match their where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, look into JOIN queries...

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Comment: Can you please give an example here on the site. That way the info will still be here if the link dies. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to Joins.

Comment: Well he's asking to search both tables for a single username, so my assumption would be that he would need a JOIN unless he wanted to do two seperate queries. What would your advice be out of curiosity @JohnieKarr?

Comment: I think he is looking for a union maybe?  I read the question as "I have two tables, employer and client.  A user name is in one of these two tables."  If the question is as Kevin Crowell put it then you are correct, JOIN is what is needed.

Comment: That's fair enough, I was just wondering what the alternative would have been. I haven't actually looked into using UNIONS before, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking to return a result where the username in Clients is also the employer  name in Employer. If so, you can do a join like this. If you need some information from the Clients table, you can just add it to your select portion of the query.

```
SELECT E.password, E.salt
FROM Employer E JOIN Clients C ON (E.Employer_Name = C.Username)
WHERE E.Employer_Name = '$username';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know to which table the user being searched, belongs, you can try this:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query1 = "SELECT password, salt
    FROM Employer
    WHERE Employer_Name = '$username';";
$query=mysql_query($query1);
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
    $from = 'Employer';
else
{
    $query2 = "SELECT password, salt
    FROM Client
    WHERE Client_Name = '$username';";
    $query=mysql_query($query2);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
        $from = 'Client';
    else
        $from='none';
}
```